# Unit Testing method failing which contains lambda expression Android Studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, lambda

#### Problem Description

I have written a simple example which is using Lambda expression. The code is working fine until I run a unit test on it. As soon as I run the unit test, it fails because of the error below

#### Environment

Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3

#### Error

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_76-release). Please
>   file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page
>   (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database
>   (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the
>   following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
>
> :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

**RxDefer.java**

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;

class RxDefer {

    private Observable<Integer> getInt() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> aSubscriber) {
                if (aSubscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                    return;

                aSubscriber.onNext(42);
                aSubscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }

    void createDefer() {
        Observable.defer(RxDefer.this::getInt).subscribe(aInteger -> {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(aInteger));
        });
    }
}
```

**RxDeferTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(RxDefer.class)
public class RxDeferTest {

    @Test
    public void createDefer() {
        RxDefer defer = new RxDefer();
        defer.createDefer();
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    testCompile(
            'junit:junit:4.12'
            , 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
            , 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4'
            , 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4'
            , 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4'
            , 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your dependencies you are using the Jack$Jill compiler of android studio to use lambda expressions. I would rather suggest using [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda).
You can checkout this post for more info on how to configure from this [link](https://medium.com/@vedprakashrout/lamda-expressions-in-java-8-and-android-studio-e0ad2cc11f82#.a00gjucpg).

> Benifits of retrolambda:
>
> You can use it also with build tool version bellow than 24.0.0 which
>   is not the case with jack compiler.

And as suggested above this issue seems fixed in retrolambda.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a fixed error in grade-retrolambda. Did you update your build to the current version?

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/23